# Problema en bash con "2>&1"

Tags: linux, bash, script, linux-mint

En mi script, tengo los siguiente:

```
sript()
{} > script.log > 2>&1
```

pero eso lo que hace es ejecutar la script directamente dentro del fichero por lo que el usuario no puede ver lo que está pasando... Como puedo hacer para que se muestre la ejecución y a la vez que me lo guarde en un fichero?

Comment: necesitaríamos más contexto sobre lo que tienes, qué quieres y qué pasa ahora

Answer (score 2):

Quiere el comando tee.

```
script() | tee script.log
```

Eso muestra en la pantalla y guarda en el fichero.

Answer (score 1):

El command [tee](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tee-invocation.html) es el que te permite redirigir a un fichero y a la consola al mismo tiempo, prueba lo siguiente:

```
command > 2>&1 | tee output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta usando el token `|&` y el comando `tee`:

```
$ comando |& tee archivo.log
```

De esta manera, el error estandar será redirigida a la salida estandar, y esta será mostrada en la pantalla y al mismo tiempo guardada en el archivo `archivo.log`.